# For loop for charting in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop, matplotlib

I want to create a chart with a for loop. X-axis is plotted correctly and even y-axis scale is set correctly, but no actual line chart is created.
What could be wrong with the code below?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib

test = {'date':[2012, 2013, 2014, 2015],'val':[9,15,12,20]}

test_df=pd.DataFrame(data=test)

test_df=test_df.set_index('date')

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(25,25))

for i in range(0, len(test_df)):
    
    ax.plot(test_df.index[i], test_df['val'].iloc[i], color='blue', linewidth=10)
        
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

You could either plot the whole series with:

```
ax.plot(test_df.index, test_df['val'], color='blue', linewidth=10)
```

and **no `for` loop**

Or plot the points themselves with:

```
ax.plot(test_df.index[i], test_df['val'].iloc[i], "b+", linewidth=10)
```

See [matplotlib's markers](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/markers_api.html) for individual points markers

Comment: Thank you, this solved the issue for me! "b+" didn't work itself, but other markers did.

Answer (score 1):

Yo do not give coordinates to plot a line which leads us to plot a scatter plot.

```
for i in range(0, len(test_df)): 
    ax.scatter(test_df.index[i], test_df['val'].iloc[i], color='blue', linewidth=10)
```

As far as I'm concerned, this would solve your problem but if you really want to connect those dots then you might give it a shot without a for loop:

```
ax.plot(test_df.index, test_df['val'], color='blue', linewidth=10)
```